# Interchange ids of android database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview

How to go about if i want to interchange the contents of my android data base as shown below:

before

```
1     hello    world
2     Android  Nougat
```

after

```
1     Android  Nougat
2     hello    world
```

Comment: For what. What exactly you want to use it for?

Comment: I'm using it for my recyclerview(drag and drop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change the positions in Database. You need to add additional int value to a database (not id). And change this value according to a new position. For first object you make it 2; for a second - 1. And when you retrieve data from your database you just sort it according to this value.

Example

```
String orderBy =  "POSITION ASC";
Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, logTableColumns, null, null,
     null, null, orderBy);
```

Comment: how to sort ??, i mean can you provide me the code??

Comment: how  to add additional int value to a database (not id).

Comment: How you created database?

Comment: only add a extra column??

Comment: Yes. Just add extra column and use it to sort your data

Comment: what is logTableColumns??

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class QueueDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public QueueDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "queue.sqlite";

    //Table names
    public static final String TABLE_QUEUE = "Queue";

    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";

    public static final String KEY_SNAME  = "key_sname";
    public static final String KEY_ANAME  = "key_aname";
    public static final String KEY_URL = "key_url";
    public static final String KEY_ORDER = "key_order";
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_QUEUE= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + TABLE_QUEUE
            + "("
            + KEY_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + KEY_SNAME
            + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ANAME
            + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_URL
            + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ORDER
            + " TEXT "
            +")";



    public long insertQueue(ArrayList<Music> mTaskArr)
    {
        long row_id = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        for(int i = 0;i<mTaskArr.size() ;i++) {

            values.put(KEY_SNAME, mTaskArr.get(i).getTitle());
            values.put(KEY_ANAME, mTaskArr.get(i).getArtist());
            values.put(KEY_URL, mTaskArr.get(i).getUrl());
                    row_id = db.insert(TABLE_QUEUE, null, values);
        }
        db.close();


        return row_id;
    }
    public void updateOrder(long rowID, int newPos) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_ORDER, newPos);
        db.update(TABLE_QUEUE, cv, KEY_ID + "=" + rowID, null);
    }
    public boolean updateQueue (Integer id, String S, String A, String U) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_SNAME,S);
        contentValues.put(KEY_ANAME,A);
        contentValues.put(KEY_URL,U);
        db.update(TABLE_QUEUE, contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
        return true;
    }
    public void dropTable() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "drop table " + TABLE_QUEUE;
        try {
            db.execSQL(sql);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<Music> getAllQueue() {

        ArrayList<Music> ar = new ArrayList<Music>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUEUE;
        //Log.d("QUERY",""+selectQuery);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Music r = new Music();

                r.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
                r.setTitle( c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SNAME)));
                r.setArtist( c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANAME)));
                r.setUrl(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_URL)));

                ar.add(r);

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();

        return ar;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_QUEUE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void arrange() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] rank = new String[]{ QueueDatabase.KEY_ID };
        Cursor c = db.query(QueueDatabase.TABLE_QUEUE, rank, null, null, null, null, QueueDatabase.KEY_ORDER+" ASC");
    }
}
```

this is how u enter data in database:

```
 q.add(new Music(T, U, A));
qd.insertQueue(q);
```